# Using .NET Core 2.0 implementation of Concurrent classes from .NET Framework application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I would like to use the .NET Core 2.0 implementations of the Concurrent and Generic collections referenced [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/06/07/performance-improvements-in-net-core/) from a .NET framework application.  Creating a .NET Standard library, wrapping these classes, and referencing the project in a .NET Framework App does not appear to work.  Instead, it runs the .NET Framework versions of the classes (which makes sense.)

Is there any way to do this? Our application relies on many Framework features that aren't in Core, so unfortunately we can't just convert it into a Core application.

Comment: It appears you confuse .NETStandard with .NETCore.  .NETStandard is only a laundry list of types that help you write portable code, it is not an implementation.  If you have no hope of porting it then there is excessively little reason to use .NETStandard.

Comment: @HansPassant - I'm not sure what you are getting at here. There are two separate implementations of the System.Collections.Concurrent library. The  .NET Core 2.0 implementation has a number of performance improvements over the implementation of the same classes in .NET Framework 4.7.1. I want to be able to take advantage of those improvements by linking the new implementation into an application that is otherwise using the .NET Framework libraries.

Comment: The mention of '.NET Standard' is purely in regards to a method I tried to use for wrapping the .NET Core implementations so that they could be distinguished in code from the .NET Framework implementations of the same-named classes.

Comment: No, there are two *reference assemblies* that define those types.  Only used to compile your code.  When you run your program then you use the actual implementation of those types.  So the 4.7.1 flavor.  A reference assembly cannot make your code faster.

Comment: I would be nice if when you have a full .NET Framework project that references a .NET Core NuGet package it could take advantage of the new and improved code. This only happens if the .NET Core NuGet package does not have an implementation in the full .NET Framework. So for concurrent collections I'm unable to take advantage of the improvements while I can use something like ASP.NET Core in a full .NET Framework project without problems.